# Server-side paging with DevExpress without XPO

Tags: .net, asp.net, winforms, paging, devexpress

Is there any (relatively) easy way to implement server-side paging using DevExpress controls (either Win- or Web-ones) without using an XPO data source? By server-side paging I mean control retrieving only the records it needs to display from the database, not the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

You must create custom paging control (Don' t use DevEx' s paging).
Send current page and page size to procedure as parameter or use directly in your query.

How to use this value sample in MS SQL is this link :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

In Oracle and other databases, you can do it too with different tecniques.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If your data source is LINQ-capable, recent DevExpress versions should be able to do the right thing.

Otherwise, you need to implement IListServer. I'm struggling with the same thing right now, so this is not exactly an "answer". I have not found a working example, but there's some useful information in their knowledge base here: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A1022.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment, would you mind pointing me to some docs on how to make it work with LINQ-capable sources?

Comment: http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2008/03/25/aspxgridview-screencast-enable-server-mode-using-linq.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use LINQ you could try this example for an ObjectDataSource: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E166.aspx